# Grouping gridview with SQL Server table only add 1 item pr id

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, gridview, grouping

I have an issue where it will only add 1 item from the table per id.

I have 2 tables, the first `Data.Mærke` contains the id and name for the group description and second `Data.Hjuldata` that contains the id from the `Data.Mærke` and id for the items and all the items

[image]

Strings

```
string connStrings = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Sql"];

string Data = @"Select ps.Mærket AS SubCategoryName, P.DataID, P.Billed, P.Model, P.Årgang, P.[Motor Type], P.Krydsmål, P.Centerhul, P.Møtrikker, P.Bolter, P.Dæk, P.Fælge from Data.Hjuldata P  inner join Data.Mærke PS on P.DataID = PS.MærkeID";
```

Code

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    BindData();

    ICollectionView dataView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(hjuldata.ItemsSource);

    dataView.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("SubCategoryName"));
}

private void BindData()
{
    hjuldata.ItemsSource = RetrieveProductsbySubCat().Tables[0].DefaultView;    
}

public DataSet RetrieveProductsbySubCat()
{
    //SQL statement to fetch entries from products
    DataSet dsProducts = new DataSet();

    //Open SQL Connection
    using (SqlConnection conns = new SqlConnection(connStrings))
    {
        conns.Open();

        //Initialize command object
        using (SqlCommand cmds = new SqlCommand(Data, conns))
        {
            SqlDataAdapter adapters = new SqlDataAdapter(cmds);

            //Fill the result set
            adapters.Fill(dsProducts);
        }
    }

    return dsProducts;
}
```

Audi is id 39 and jaguar is id 38 and under Jaguar I have 220 items with the exact same `Mærkeid` but only 1 is being showed up[image: The Data i getting]

Comment: Could you provide a sample of the data you are getting, and then also a sample of how you are expecting it?

Comment: i have updatet it and i want all my 220 jaguar models to be showed under the jaguar group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are joining on the wrong column in you query, try the following:

```sql
Select ps.Mærket AS SubCategoryName, P.DataID, P.Billed, P.Model, 
       P.Årgang, P.[Motor Type], P.Krydsmål, P.Centerhul, P.Møtrikker, 
       P.Bolter, P.Dæk, P.Fælge 
from Data.Hjuldata P  
join Data.Mærke PS 
on P.MærkeID = PS.MærkeID;
```

You were trying to join on `P.DataID = PS.MærkeID` in your original query. That didn't seem correct.